# Clarification Around "Duality" of Service Accounts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-run, service-accounts

I have two Cloud Run services. `Service U` has Unauthenticated access open to all users. `Service R` I want the access Restricted so that only `Service A` can invoke it.

[This gist](https://github.com/meteatamel/cloudrun-tutorial/blob/master/docs/auth.md) has a pretty succinct implementation using the CLI. My services are configured with Terraform and I'm trying to translate, but also understand:

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65302141/1252748) I thought I could allow Service R access by Service U by adding U's service account (I added `service_account: service-u-sa@abcdefg.iam.gserviceaccount.com` to Service U's `google_cloud_run_service.spec.service_account_name`) in the same way I open up access to all users. Here is allUsers:

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "service_r" {
  name                       = local.service_name
  # ... rest of the service definition
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_member" "run_all_users" {
  service  = google_cloud_run_service.service_r.name
  location = google_cloud_run_service.service_r.location
  role     = "roles/run.invoker"
  member   = "allUsers"
  depends_on = [
    google_cloud_run_service.service_r,
  ]
}
```

And I amended it to be for just one service account with:

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_member" "run_all_users" {
  service  = google_cloud_run_service.service_r.name
  location = google_cloud_run_service.service_r.location
  role     = "roles/run.invoker"
  member = "serviceAccount:service-u-sa@abcdefg.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  depends_on = [
    google_cloud_run_service.service_b,
  ]
}
```

This does not seem to work.

However, adding a data source that creates a policy does seem to work:

```
data "google_iam_policy" "access_policy" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/run.invoker"
    members = [
      "serviceAccount:service-u-sa@abcdefg.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    ]
  }
}

resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_policy" "cloud_run_policy" {
  location    = google_cloud_run_service.service_r.location
  project     = google_cloud_run_service.service_r.project
  service     = google_cloud_run_service.service_r.name

  policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.access_policy.policy_data
}
```

I've read on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61878052) (and elsewhere) that service accounts are identities *as well as* resources. Is that what is happening here? That is, rather than using the service account `service-b-sa@abcdefg.iam.gserviceaccount.com` as an identity, I am attaching it to Service R as a "resource"? Is that what a "policy" is in this context? And is there anywhere in the GCR UI where I can see these relationships?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I will try to clarify the wording and the situation, even if I didn't catch what changed between your 2 latest piece of code.

**Duality**

Yes, Service Account have duality: they are identity AND resources. And because they are a resource, you can grant on identity on it (especially to perform impersonation).

**Access Policy**

It's simply a binding between an identity and a role. Then you have to apply that binding to a resource to grant the identity the role on the resource. This trio is an IAM authorization policy, or policy in short.

**Service and Service Account**

Your question is hard to understand because you mix the Cloud Run service, and the service account.

A Cloud Run service has an identity: the runtime service account.

A Cloud Run service CAN'T have access to another Cloud Run service. But the identity of a Cloud Run service can access another Cloud Run service.

---

That being said, there is no difference between your 2 latest piece of code. In fact yes, there is a difference but the second definition is much more restrictive than the first one.

In the latest one, you use `....._iam_policy`. It means you REPLACE all the policies. In other word, the "access_policy" override all the existing permissions.

In the case before, you use `....._iam_member`. It means you simply add a policy to the current resource, without changing the existing ones.

That's why, the result is the same: `service-u` has the role Invoker on the service_r.

Can you try again? the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: “even if I didn't catch what changed between your 2 latest piece of code.”: do you mean the edit (I just fixed some naming) or the two code blocks thar are really similar—the only difference is `member = “allUsers”` and `member = “ serviceaccount:service-u-sa@abcdefg.iam.gserviceaccount.com”`? Thanks, I’m reviewing this answer now, just wondered where I need to provide more clarity.

Comment: service-u-sa was added to service u via google_could_run_service [service_account_name prop](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_service#service_account_name). So that is the “runtime service account” identity.  That makes sense. And I apply it as a resource to the other cloud run instance. Seems straightforward.  But this I don’t follow ➡️ “ Your question is hard to understand because you mix the Cloud Run service, and the service account.” how am I mixing them? (Incorrectly?)

Comment: Also, terminology question here: are both `resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_policy"` and `resource resource "google_cloud_run_service_iam_member“` operations to _”apply”_ a service account as a “resource”? Thanks again.

Comment: “And because they are a resource, you can grant on identity on it (especially to perform impersonation).” This seems like the inverse of using a service-account-as-identity to attach a policy to a resource, eg cloud run resource. Correct? Can you explain how that’s done?